# IPAM (IP address management)

Tags: ipv4, ipam

Could any one please explain the difference between Splitting and Allocation a IP address block.

Say if I have 10.0.0.0/24 (254 hosts) available. My requirement is to get a /25. 
Could anyone explain how Splitting and Allocation works?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do some subnetting.

On this link everything is clearly explained:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork